# Average stock value calculation

Tags: stocks, investment-strategies, price, value-averaging

Let's say I buy 1000 shares of ABC for 10$ each.
Avg. Cost : 10$

Six months later I sell 500 shares for 12$ each.
Total earnings: 1000$

Question: should I include the earnings in the formula of the avg. cost in order to drive the avg. share cost lower?

Answer (score 2):

You bought 1,000 shares at $10 and sold 500 shares at $12.  That's a $1,000 gain.

When you sell the remaining 500 shares, what will you put on your taxes as the cost basis?  It will be what you paid for them which is $10.

If you like, you can  calculate other stats regarding your trades but the cost basis is what you paid for the shares.